# Game is darker on build

Tags: unity, lighting, build-process

I've been recently doing test builds of my game. In Unity, I worked on baking the lighting to ensure everything looked fine. However, upon building, the game level becomes far darker and much of the lighting and baking is ineffective.

Here is how the scene looks in the editor:
[image: Brightly lit image of a library]

And here is how it looks in the built game:
[image: Darker image of a library]

It's much darker than intended.

Here are my lighting settings which I've baked in Unity's Editor. These settings and lightmap parameters were designed to, at least in the editor, provide decent quality while making light bake times relatively quick. However, I've noticed that newer Unity's Lighting settings are way different now, so perhaps something is amiss here?
[image]

I've been at my wits end trying to figure this out for the past while, but I can't figure out why this is happening or how to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't forget to include enough information about your lighting setup & configuration in the scene / graphics settings in the project so that we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Added an image of my Lighting settings. Lights are one directional realtime light and several mixed spotlights. This has been an issue on default, but I have been experimenting with changing several of the project settings for a while and nothing seems to have changed. This includes the graphic settings, which hasn't seemed to improve anything so far. What should I be looking for?

Comment: Which version of Unity are you using?

Comment: Unity 2017.3.0f3

Answer (score 3):

Unity will only take lighting from the active scene. So it's worth checking that:

1. The scene is the "Active Scene" (bold highlight in hierarchy) when
   building lighting in the Edit Mode
2. The scene is either the only loaded scene in Play Mode or you call
   SceneManager.SetActiveScene( scene ) for whichever scene you wish to
   take the lighting data from.

see: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.SetActiveScene.html